# How does Dell update drivers through the browser?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, dell-inspiron

Does anyone know how Dell can update drivers on my Dell by me just visiting their driver download page? The browser doesn't prompt me to download files or anything, but some how Dell is able to update their drivers by me just following the prompt on their site. Does Dell SupportAssist hijack my Chrome browser or something? I don't remember granting them such permissions. By what mechanism are they achieving this type of integration and can anyone else have this power over my computer?

Similarly, how does Dell detect my computer model and service tag number through the browser?

And just for knowledge sake, is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: _"is there a way to prevent this from happening?"_ - don't install tools of which only purpose is to make this possible.

Comment: @gronostaj is likely correct. However they're assuming OP installed it likely when Dell did. Also no one appreciates sass, don't answer questions if you don't want to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work is being done by Dell
[SupportAssist](https://www.dell.com/support/contents/en-us/article/product-support/self-support-knowledgebase/software-and-downloads/supportassist).

Dell installs a system service on your computer which is called
"Dell SupportAssist" and is implemented by the executable
`C:\Program Files\Dell\SupportAssistAgent\bin\SupportAssistAgent.exe`
that has the following description:

> Dell SupportAssist keeps your PC up to date and running at its best with recommended software and driver updates. It also helps resolve issues quickly by detecting common problems and sending issue details to Dell Technical Support agents on your behalf.

This System Service has the Startup type of Automatic, so is started
when the computer is booted. It runs under the Local System account,
so has unlimited access to your computer.

In addition, it installs a local HTTPS proxy that can be queried at
the URL of `https://127.0.0.1:8884`, so is listening on port 8884
locally on your computer.

The Dell support page at https://www.dell.com/support/drivers queries
SupportAssistAgent through this port via JavaScript code on the page,
to receive the Service Tag and the list of installed drivers.
With this information it queries Dell for the list of drivers that
require update.

The driver is downloaded from Dell using the request URL of
`http://127.0.0.1:8884/downloadservice/...`, so the download is actually
done by the SupportAssistAgent System Service, which also has no problem
with installing the updates, as it operates with system-level permissions
(meaning that it's a part of Windows for all practical purposes).

To block the system service, you will need to disable it.
The simplest way is to run *Start > Services*, find the
"Dell SupportAssist" service and change its Startup type to Disabled.
The service will then no longer start with Windows, so will not be
available.

If you decide on doing that, you might just as well uninstall
SupportAssist entirely via
*Control Panel > Programs and Features*.

Comment: Solid answer. It feels great to have this mystery solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you have the [Dell SupportAssist](https://www.dell.com/support/contents/en-ed/article/product-support/self-support-knowledgebase/software-and-downloads/supportassist) tool (or a variant of it) installed on your system.

From your browser the web page likely communicates via a server process in the support tool to establish what drivers are installed, trigger downloads and installation.

Uninstalling the tool and any other Dell frameworks will likely prevent the website from knowing your service tag.